# holding 2^63 -1 in long long

Tags: c++

I ran the following two pieces of code on Windows XP (Code:Block, MinGW),  and Ubuntu (11.04,  G++)

I have trouble running the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    long long a = 9223372036854775807;
    cout <<  a;
    return 0;

}
```

That number is 2^63 -1.  But I will get an error stating:

> C:\Documents and Settings\JohnWong\My
>   Documents\codeblock\343_hw_1\main.cpp|9|error: integer constant is too
>   large for "long" type|

On ubuntu - it compiled, but the answer retunred is  9223372036854775808,  notice the 8 at the end....

Now if I run this code, using the power function, I am okay.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    long long a = pow(2,64);
    cout << "a:   " << setprecision(20) << a << endl;
    cout << "a-1:   " << setprecision(20) << a-1 << endl;
    cout << "a-2:   " <<  setprecision(20) << a-2 << endl;
    cout << "a+0:   " << setprecision(20) << a+0 << endl;
    cout << "a+1:   " << setprecision(20) << a+1 << endl;
    cout << "a+2:   " << setprecision(20) << a+2 << endl;
    cout << "a+3:   " << setprecision(20) << a+3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I will get the values I want (anything from +1 will cause an overflow, that's okay).

On Ubuntu the outputs looks the same. Good.

So what's going on here? Why constant is not good??? 
I even tried  intmax_t  and int64_t  as datatype running the first code.

Can someone explain this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
long long a = 9223372036854775807LL;
```

The LL makes the literal a long long literal. Otherwise the literal defaults to being a long literal and then is casted over to a long long before being stored in a.

Comment: @Eric, umm.. yes it did. Reference the warning he put in the post. Why the compiler doesn't automatically upgrade... I don't know.

Comment: The `LL` should not be required.  "The type of a [suffixless] integer literal is the first in [the following list] in which its value can be represented:  `int`, `long int`, `long long int`." (from C++11 2.14.2/2; C99 has language that says practically the same thing, and C++03 has the same language but excludes `long long int` because that wasn't part of C++03).  While the proposed solution of adding `LL` may work on some compilers, it should not be required (Visual C++ 2010, g++ 4.5.1, and Clang 3.0 all accept the code without the `LL`).

Comment: @James, interesting. I get a warning on g++ 4.4.3. Perhaps the issue is that these compilers aren't c++11 compatible yet?

Answer (score 1):

C++ language did not have `long long` type before C++11. Your compiler is apparently not a C++11 compiler, and it supports `long long` as an extension. This is  why the compiler issues the warning. It warns you that the literal is interpreted in a non-standard (extended) way, i.e. that while searching for the appropriate type for the literal, the compiler had to go outside the bounds of the language standard.